# ViewModel is not getting cleared in onDestroyView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

i am using fragment to observe livedata in fragment. Whenever i shift to another fragment let say fragment B ,and then again to A ,the same view model is assigned to the fragment A with existing LivaData like the previous one and it starts responding to the previous live data

**This is my fragment**

```
  class Notifications : BaseFragment<FragmentNotificationsBinding>(),RecyclerListner {
        private var batcheDailog: AlertDialog? = null
        private var dailogview: View? = null
        private var document_id: String? = null
        private var document_url: String? = null
        private lateinit var notificationViewModel: NotificationViewModel
        private lateinit var adapter: NotificationHistory
        private var SEM1_SELECTED:Boolean = false
        private var SEM2_SELECTED:Boolean = false
        private var SEM3_SELECTED:Boolean = false
        private var SEM4_SELECTED:Boolean = false
        private var SEM5_SELECTED:Boolean = false
        private var SEM6_SELECTED:Boolean = false
        override val layoutId: Int
            get() = R.layout.fragment_notifications
    
        override fun init() {
           notificationViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotificationViewModel::class.java)
            Log.d("viewmodel",notificationViewModel.toString())
            val  option = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<NotificationDto>()
                .setQuery(Reference.Notification_Ref, NotificationDto::class.java)
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .build()
            adapter = NotificationHistory(this,option)
            binding.rvHistory.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            binding.rvHistory.adapter = adapter
            val callback: ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback = object :
                ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
    
                override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
                ) {
                    RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                        .addBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.red))
                        .addActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete)
                        .addSwipeRightLabel("Delete")
                        .setSwipeRightLabelTextSize(Dimension.DP,45f)
                        .setSwipeRightLabelColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!,R.color.white))
                        .create()
                        .decorate()
                    super.onChildDraw(c,recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                }
    
                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                  document_id =  adapter.snapshots.getSnapshot(viewHolder.adapterPosition).reference.id
                    document_url = adapter.snapshots.getSnapshot(viewHolder.adapterPosition).getString("document_url")
                 if(Validator.validateNull(document_url)) notificationViewModel.deleteNotification(document_id!!)
                    else notificationViewModel.deleteAttachment(document_url!!)
    
                }
            }
            val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(callback)
            itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.rvHistory)
           val yoyo = mutableListOf<String>()
            yoyo.add("SEM-1")
            yoyo.add("SEM-2")
            yoyo.add("SEM-3")
            yoyo.add("SEM-4")
            initdailog(yoyo)
            setlistner()
          setobserver()
           // notificationViewModel.getBatchLList()
    
        }
    
        private fun initdailog(batches: List<*>) {
             dailogview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dailog_select_sem,null,false)
            if(!batches.contains("SEM-1")) dailogview!!.toogle_batches.btn_sem1.visibility = View.GONE
            if(!batches.contains("SEM-2")) dailogview!!.toogle_batches.btn_sem2.visibility = View.GONE
            if(!batches.contains("SEM-3")) dailogview!!.toogle_batches.btn_sem3.visibility = View.GONE
            if(!batches.contains("SEM-4")) dailogview!!.toogle_batches.btn_sem4.visibility = View.GONE
            if(!batches.contains("SEM-5")) dailogview!!.toogle_batches.btn_sem5.visibility = View.GONE
            if(!batches.contains("SEM-6")) dailogview!!.toogle_batches.btn_sem6.visibility = View.GONE
           batcheDailog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context).create()
            dailogview!!.toogle_batches.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
                if(isChecked){
                    when(checkedId){
                        R.id.btn_sem1-> SEM1_SELECTED = true
                        R.id.btn_sem2-> SEM2_SELECTED = true
                        R.id.btn_sem3-> SEM3_SELECTED = true
                        R.id.btn_sem4-> SEM4_SELECTED = true
                        R.id.btn_sem5-> SEM5_SELECTED = true
                        R.id.btn_sem6-> SEM6_SELECTED = true
                    }
                }
                else{
                    when(checkedId){
                        R.id.btn_sem1-> SEM1_SELECTED = false
                        R.id.btn_sem2-> SEM2_SELECTED = false
                        R.id.btn_sem3-> SEM3_SELECTED = false
                        R.id.btn_sem4-> SEM4_SELECTED = false
                        R.id.btn_sem5-> SEM5_SELECTED = false
                        R.id.btn_sem6-> SEM6_SELECTED = false
                    }
                }
            }
    
            dailogview!!.btn_next.setOnClickListener {
                if(!SEM1_SELECTED && !SEM2_SELECTED &&!SEM3_SELECTED && !SEM4_SELECTED && !SEM5_SELECTED && !SEM6_SELECTED ) showToast("Select At Least One",0)
                else{
                    val selectedBatches = ArrayList<String>()
                    if(SEM1_SELECTED) selectedBatches.add("SEM-1")
                    if(SEM2_SELECTED) selectedBatches.add("SEM-2")
                    if(SEM3_SELECTED) selectedBatches.add("SEM-3")
                    if(SEM4_SELECTED) selectedBatches.add("SEM-4")
                    if(SEM5_SELECTED) selectedBatches.add("SEM-5")
                    if(SEM6_SELECTED) selectedBatches.add("SEM-6")
    
                    startActivity(SendNotification.getCallingIntent(context!!,selectedBatches))
    
                }
    
            }
    
            batcheDailog!!.setView(dailogview)
        }
    
        private fun setobserver() {
            notificationViewModel.getBatchLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                when(it.status){
                    ResponseData.Status.LOADING -> showLoadingDailog("Please Wait",it.message!!)
                    ResponseData.Status.SUCCESS -> {val batches = it.data as List<*>
                        hideLoadingDailog()
                        initdailog(batches)
                    }
                    ResponseData.Status.ERROR -> showErrorDailog("Error",it.message!!)
    
                }
            })
            notificationViewModel.getdeleteAttachmentLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                when(it.status){
                    ResponseData.Status.LOADING -> showLoadingDailog("Please Wait",it.message!!)
                    ResponseData.Status.SUCCESS -> notificationViewModel.deleteNotification(document_id!!)
                    ResponseData.Status.ERROR -> showErrorDailog("Error",it.message!!)
    
                }
            })
            notificationViewModel.getdeleteNotificationData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                when(it.status){
                    ResponseData.Status.LOADING -> showLoadingDailog("Please Wait",it.message!!)
                    ResponseData.Status.SUCCESS -> showSuccessDailog("Done","Deleted Successfully")
                    ResponseData.Status.ERROR -> showErrorDailog("Error",it.message!!)
    
                }
            })
    
    
    
    
        }
    
        private fun setlistner() {
    
            binding.btnNotificationHistory.setOnClickListener {
                binding.clMain.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.clHistory.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    
            }
            binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener{
                binding.clHistory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.clMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
    
            binding.btnSelectbatch.setOnClickListener {
                batcheDailog!!.show()
            }
    
            batcheDailog!!.setOnCancelListener {
                SEM1_SELECTED = false
                SEM2_SELECTED = false
                SEM3_SELECTED = false
                SEM4_SELECTED = false
                SEM5_SELECTED = false
                SEM6_SELECTED = false
    
                dailogview!!.toogle_batches.clearChecked()
            }
    
            binding.btnAllbatch.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(SendNotification.getCallingIntent(context!!,null))
            }
        }
    
        override fun onClick(id: String, notificationDto: NotificationDto) {
            startActivity(ActivityNotificationDetail.getCallingIntent(context!!,notificationDto,id))
        }
    
    }
```

**This is my viewModel**

```
class NotificationViewModel:BaseViewModel() {

    val  getUploadDocumentLiveData:MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>> = MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>>()
    val  getSendNotificationLiveData:MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>> = MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>>()
    val  getBatchLiveData:MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>> = MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>>()
    val  getdeleteAttachmentLiveData:MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>> = MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>>()
    val  getdeleteNotificationData:MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>> = MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>>()
    val  getUpdateNotificationLiveData:MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>> = MutableLiveData<ResponseData<Any>>()


    fun sendNotification(notificationDto: NotificationDto){
        getSendNotificationLiveData.value = ResponseData.loading("Sending Notification")
        compositeDisposable.add(repository!!.sendNotification(notificationDto).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
               subscribe({
                   getSendNotificationLiveData.value = ResponseData.success()
               },{
                   getSendNotificationLiveData.value = ResponseData.error(it.message!!)
               })
        )
    }


    fun uploadDocument(path:Uri,reference: StorageReference){
        getUploadDocumentLiveData.value = ResponseData.loading("Uploading Document. This may take some time depending on the file size")
        compositeDisposable.add(repository!!.getUrl(path, reference).
        observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
        subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
        subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<String>(){
            override fun onSuccess(t: String) {
                getUploadDocumentLiveData.value = ResponseData.success("Done",t)
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                getUploadDocumentLiveData.value = ResponseData.error(e.message!!)
            }
        }))
    }

    fun updateNotification(id:String,notificationDto: NotificationDto){
        getUpdateNotificationLiveData.value = ResponseData.loading("This may take some time depending on the file size")
        compositeDisposable.add(repository!!.updateNotification(id, notificationDto).
        observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
        subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
        subscribe({
            getUpdateNotificationLiveData.value = ResponseData.success()
        },{
            getUpdateNotificationLiveData.value = ResponseData.error(it.message!!)
        }))
    }

    fun deleteAttachment(url:String){
        getdeleteAttachmentLiveData.value = ResponseData.loading("Connecting To the server")
        compositeDisposable.add(repository!!.deleteFile(url).
        observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
        subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
       subscribe({
           getdeleteAttachmentLiveData.value = ResponseData.success()
       },{
           getdeleteAttachmentLiveData.value = ResponseData.error(it.message!!)
       }))
    }
    fun deleteNotification(id:String){
        getdeleteNotificationData.value = ResponseData.loading("Deleting Notification")
        compositeDisposable.add(repository!!.deleteNotification(id).
        observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
        subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
        subscribe({
            getdeleteNotificationData.value = ResponseData.success()
        },{
            getdeleteNotificationData.value = ResponseData.error(it.message!!)
        }))
    }

}
```

**This is my fragmentManger Class**

```
class DashboardAdapter(manager:FragmentManager):FragmentPagerAdapter(manager, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position){
            0-> return Notifications()
            1-> return Batches()
            2-> return Updates()
            else ->  return Notifications()
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int = 3
}
```

This is my BaseFragment**

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : ViewDataBinding> : Fragment() {

        abstract val layoutId: Int
        protected lateinit var binding: T

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)
            return binding.root
        }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        init()
    }

        abstract fun init()


    fun showToast(msg:String,duration:Int){
      getBaseActivity().showToast(msg,duration)

    }

    fun hideLoadingDailog(){
       getBaseActivity().hideLoadingDailog()
    }

    fun showLoadingDailog(title:String,msg:String){
       getBaseActivity().showLoadingDailog(title,msg)
    }
    fun showLoadingDailog(title:String,msg:String,animid:Int){
        getBaseActivity().showLoadingDailog(title,msg,animid)
    }



    fun showSuccessDailog(title:String,msg:String){
       getBaseActivity().showSuccessDailog(title,msg)
    }
    fun showErrorDailog(title:String,msg:String){
           getBaseActivity().showErrorDailog(title,msg)

    }
    fun showFinalDailog(title:String,msg:String,positivebutton :String,negativebutton:String,listner: AbstractDialog.OnClickListener){
       getBaseActivity().showFinalDailog(title,msg,positivebutton,negativebutton,listner)

    }
    fun showFinalDailog(title:String,msg:String,positivebutton :String,listner:  AbstractDialog.OnClickListener){
        getBaseActivity().showFinalDailog(title,msg,positivebutton,listner)

    }
    protected fun getBaseActivity(): BaseActivity<*> {
            return (activity as BaseActivity<*>)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `ViewModel`s are stored in `ViewModelStore` to be used later. When you come back to previous fragment it restores the same instance of `ViewModel`. If you want to refresh a data, you can make some network request or pull data from DB in that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In your `BaseFragment`, you are calling init from `onActivityCreated`(which is deprecated in case you did not know).

Instead override the method `onViewCreated` and Call `init` from it.

Comment: previously i was doing the same thing its not working